# LWC - map function is working on console but not on the page

Tags: lightning-web-components, map, console

The idea is to remove duplicate id's upon selection of records using checkbox. Below is the code used.

```
selectedTaskObj3 = [];
let el = this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable");
let selectedRowsArray = el.getSelectedRows();
//**note**: until here I get the output as an object array
let selectedTaskObjChecktest = JSON.stringify(selectedRowsArray).map((item)=>item.Id)
this.selectedTaskObj3 = Array.from(new Set(selectedTaskObjChecktest));
```

However it is working perfect in console log but not on the page which is totally strange.

[image: The output from the console log]

Comment: You `JSON.stringify` the data, thus making a "string", so the map function would fail.

Comment: Also, you're not even using `JSON.stringify` in the console. You have your `objArray` object, which you then call `map` on. What happens in your code above when you call `selectedRowsArray.map`?

Comment: Oh okay, it throws me a script error

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for your response . I got it now. Removed the JSON.stringify now and tried. For some reason I did not try to use directly without stringyfying. Now it works perfect.

Answer (score 4):

You do not `JSON.stringify` an Array before attempting to use Array methods, such as `Array.prototype.map`.